# Autocomplete doesn't work in netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.4

Please help me, when I create a new php-zend framework project and I indicate a public folder as web root folder. But when I am typing a slash  Autocomplete doesn't work! What's the problem? In netbeans 7.3 the path to the public root work's correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the patches? There was a [bug regarding code completion](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236938) in PHP in Netbeans 7.4 which has been fixed in 7.4.1 (even though 7.4.2 was released just three days ago).

Comment: In Netbeans click "Help / Check for Updates"

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning: if you are updating Netbeans via updates (and not downloading the complete IDE and re-install from scratch) the splash screen is not going to change (it will still display 7.4). But if no new updates are offered after invoking "Check for Updates" you are on the newest version.

Comment: I installed from scratch netbeans 7.4 I checked the updates, but there are no updates available. Maybe I am using windows7 and other users Linux? Thank you an advance!

Comment: Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.4 (Build 201310111528)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 7.4 Patch 2
Java: 1.7.0_45; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.45-b08
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_45-b18
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1251; en_US (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\MK\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4
Cache directory: C:\Users\MK\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.4

Comment: My bug wasn't fixed with autocomplete even the latest update)

Comment: @JoachimRohde I'm not sure what you're calling 7.4.1 and 7.4.2, but it seems there are [no such designations](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/roadmap.html). Pity, because I need the Subversion 1.8 support that was committed to nightlies months ago, but can't go straight to 8.0 yet.

Comment: Ok, seems like I mixed up a few things. I was referring to the patches (http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans7.4PatchesInfo).